# node js :Can\'t set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to send the response properly.  I like to move to another page after FTP and Telnet sessions.

Even tried using res.redirect function too.  While using res.redirect, i commented `window.location= "SaveRedirect";` line, in javascript of html page. Even then, I get the same error.

Here presenting the code snippet,

the javascript code in html

```
IPData ={
            "DeviceIpAddr": "192.168.1.2"
        };

function processSave() {

        $.post("PostSave", IPData, function(data) {
                window.location= "SaveRedirect";
        });
 return true;
}
```

node js code snippet

```
app.get('/SaveRedirect', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "Page2.htm" );
})

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var testJsonEncoder = bodyParser.json();
urlEncoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true });

app.post('/PostSave', testJsonEncoder,urlEncoded, function(request, response){

   var LoginData = JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 4);
   console.log(LoginData);
   FormDataObj = JSON.parse(LoginData);
   gDeviceIpAddress = FormDataObj.DeviceIpAddr;
   console.log("IP Address" + gDeviceIpAddress);

    console.log("FTP to linux box...");
    ftpFile(gDeviceIpAddress, "PUT", "temp_data.json", response);
    console.log("FTP temp_data file to linux box... Done!");
    TelnetLinux(gDeviceIpAddress);
    console.log("Telnet to linux box... Done!");
    response.send("just to send response");
    //response.json(LoginData);

});


function ftpFile(ftpIPAddr, operation, filename, resp) {

    console.log("ftpIPAddr = " + ftpIPAddr);

    ftpConfig.host = ftpIPAddr;

    // Handle error

    ftpClient.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log(" - ERROR HANDLE - \n");

            console.log(err);

            resp.send("FAIL: " + err.message);
            ftpClient.end();


    });


    // Handle error
    ftpClient.on("ready", function () {
        console.log("Connected....\n");
        if(operation == "GET") {
            console.log("filename  :  " + filename);
            ftpClient.get(filename, function(err, stream) {
                if (err) 
                {

                    resp.send("FAIL: " + err.message + " - " + filename);
                    ftpClient.end();

                    //throw err;
                }
                else {
                  stream.once('close', function() { ftpClient.end(); });
                  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test_data.json'));

                  resp.send("SUCCESS: file received");
                  ftpClient.end();


                }
            });
        }

        if(operation == "PUT") {
            ftpClient.put(filename, filename, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    resp.send("FAIL: " + err.message + " - " + filename);
                    ftpclient.end();
                    throw err;

                }
                else {
                    resp.send("SUCCESS:  file sent");
                    ftpClient.end();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    ftpClient.connect(ftpConfig);
}



function TelnetLinux(deviceIPAddr) {

    var telnetParams = {
      host: deviceIPAddr,
      port: 23,
      username: "webtest",
      password: "test123",
      shellPrompt: '$',
      timeout: 1500,
      // removeEcho: 4
    };

    cmd = "ls";

    console.log("Telnet Address : " + deviceIPAddr);
    telnetClient.on('ready', function(prompt) {
      telnetClient.exec(cmd, function(err, response) {
        //console.log(response);
        console.log("Cmd executed !");
      });
    });

    telnetClient.on('timeout', function() {
      console.log('telnet socket timeout!')
      telnetClient.end();
    });

    telnetClient.on('close', function() {
      console.log('telnet connection closed');
    });

    telnetClient.connect(telnetParams); 
}
```

Error :

```
c:\WebTest>node webapp.js
Example app listening at http://:::8081

IP Address192.168.1.2
FTP to linux box...
ftpIPAddr = 192.168.1.2
FTP temp_data file to linux box... Done!
Telnet Address : 192.168.1.2
Telnet to linux box... Done!
Cmd executed !
telnet socket timeout!
telnet connection closed
Connected....

_http_outgoing.js:346
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (c:\WebTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (c:\WebTest\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:164:12)
    at c:\WebTest\webapp.js:222:11
    at Object.cb (c:\WebTest\node_modules\ftp\lib\connection.js:1017:13)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (c:\WebTest\node_modules\ftp\lib\connection.js:117:20)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Parser._write (c:\WebTest\node_modules\ftp\lib\parser.js:59:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:215:11)
    at Socket.ondata (c:\WebTest\node_modules\ftp\lib\connection.js:273:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
```

Comment: You send twice response to the client, try to remove `response.send("just to send response");`

Comment: even if i remove it , it doesnt  go to page2.htm and it gives Error in html page "Failed to load resource: http://localhost:8081/PostSave the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to do `res.send` (or `response.send`) multiple times in the same call. I believe it has to do with this bit of code:

```
app.post('/PostSave', testJsonEncoder, urlEncoded, function(request, response) {

    var LoginData = JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 4);
    console.log(LoginData);
    FormDataObj = JSON.parse(LoginData);
    gDeviceIpAddress = FormDataObj.DeviceIpAddr;
    console.log("IP Address" + gDeviceIpAddress);

    console.log("FTP to linux box...");
    ftpFile(gDeviceIpAddress, "PUT", "temp_data.json", response);
    console.log("FTP temp_data file to linux box... Done!");
    TelnetLinux(gDeviceIpAddress);
    console.log("Telnet to linux box... Done!");
    response.send("just to send response");
    //response.json(LoginData);

});
```

You're doing a `response.send` at the end of this function, and again in  `ftpFile()`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending response multiple times in **app.post("/Postsave"** and **function ftpFile** for the same request, you get this error.

To resolve this, I would suggest you to send the result(or error) from the ftpfile back to the app.post(i.e., through callback) and then based on the result or error send the response from the app.post function.